# libxml2 parser question. How do i treat error messages from the server? And how do i treat timeout watchdogs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, networking, libxml2

I have a few questions about the same code sow

1. first of all how do i treat error messages from the server

if i get a unusual XML returned that does not match the type of my object my app blockes;

1. How do i treat network time out (the watchdogs)

Any other suggestion about my code will be appreciated.
My code:

```
xmlTextReaderPtr reader = xmlReaderForMemory([DecryResponse bytes], [DecryResponse length], NULL, NULL,  (XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | XML_PARSE_NOCDATA | XML_PARSE_NOERROR | XML_PARSE_NOWARNING));
        NSString * currentTagName =nil;
        NSString * currentTagValue= nil;
        char *temp = nil;
        while (true) {
            if(!xmlTextReaderRead(reader))break;
            switch (xmlTextReaderNodeType(reader)) {
                case XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT:
                    temp = (char *)xmlTextReaderConstName(reader);
                    currentTagName =[NSString stringWithCString:temp encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    continue;
               case XML_READER_TYPE_TEXT:                       
                    temp =(char *)xmlTextReaderConstValue(reader);
                    currentTagValue = [NSString stringWithCString:temp encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    if ([currentTagName  isEqual:@"Account"]) {
                        SW.Account =[currentTagValue intValue];}
                    if ([currentTagName  isEqual:@"SessionNumber"]) {
                        SW.SessionNumber = currentTagValue;         }
                    if ([currentTagName  isEqual:@"OpCode"]) {
                        SW.OpCode = [currentTagValue intValue];}
                default:continue;
            }
        }
```